# How do I renew my cert? ACMEv1 Brownout in Progress

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate, lets-encrypt

I dont know what this means, their website doesn't offer any guides, and googling it doesn't provide any help. My whole website is now inaccessible and I can't fix it.

```
Cert is due for renewal, auto-renewing...
Attempting to renew cert from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/lospec.com.conf produced an unexpected error: urn:acme:error:serverInternal :: The server experienced an internal error :: ACMEv1 Brownout in Progress. ACMEv1 will fully turn off on June 1, 2021. Check https://letsencrypt.status.io/ for more details.. Skipping.
```

Comment: Seems like maybe you need to brush up on your Google skills. - https://www.google.com/search?q=ACMEv1+Brownout+in+Progress&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS934US934&oq=ACMEv1+Brownout+in+Progress&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.501j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 - https://www.google.com/search?q=ACMEv1+will+fully+turn+off+on+June+1%2C+2021&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS934US934&oq=ACMEv1+will+fully+turn+off+on+June+1%2C+2021&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i299.493j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: none of that tells me how to fix it

Comment: **The intention is to induce client errors that might encourage subscribers to update to clients or configurations that use ACMEv2** - So the fix is to update to ACMEv2. That seems pretty clear to me. Is there a reason you can't use ACMEv2?

Comment: Off topic: Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it.

Comment: @stackers Update your certbot to a recent version.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So you use a specific software to install certs, you most likely just have to upgrade that software.

Here is how to do it with certbot (most common):

```
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade certbot
```

Comment: There's some expected minimum knowledge around here. Basic package updates on your system fit into those. Nobody was withholding information from you, they were attempting to guide you to the answers while helping you leverage your own critical thinking skills.

Comment: I didn't know that was important, the letencrypt error and website did not say that was. I do not understand it. I am a web developer, not a server manager. I know just enough to get by (though it usually helps when error messages actually tell you how to fix it)

Comment: saying "google it" is not helpful

Comment: It is sadly how you learn if you ever want to grow up in the professional space.

Comment: i know how to google tomtom, you're not a genius for thinking up that strategy. also google mostly leads here, which wouldn't exist if no one asked questions. i asked this question so it can now be on google so the next person like me can actually find an answer.